# Address mail invalid RFC, Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8

I have a problem in my code, but I don't understand the problem. The error given is:

> Address in mailbox given [Service Cotation Groupage] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

But the recipient email address I gave is: `am.name@example.com`

As you can see, the email address is formatted correctly, with no spaces.

Here is the code that is sending the email:

```php
Mail::to($mail)
    ->send(new SendCotationEmail([$message, $NumOfCot, $client, $inco]));
return true;
```

Comment: The provided email address looks correct. The error could also be caused by an incorrect email of the sender / ReplyTo. Did you perhaps define any invalid ReplyTo email in the mailable SendCotationEmail? Are you sure you the from address in your application is set to a valid email address?

Comment: Is the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` in your `.env` file correct?

Comment: Yes, the MAIL_FROM_ADRESS and reply to is correct, because if I included into :
`Mail::to("am.name@example.com")` this code works fine

Comment: The problem came only to `Mail::to()` but I don't understand why. If I do a verification before send, this return true :/

Comment: Have you tried defining the sender in the build method of your SendCotationEmail mailable?  Something like $this->from('am.name@example.com', 'Example Name')

Comment: Yes the sender from take the data from the .env ... complexe problem